# Requery using a variable within string

Tags: sql, string, vba, variables, ms-access

I am having trouble to requery my subform using a SQL string, here is my code:

```
Dim Day As Integer
Day = txt_Days.Value         
SQL = "SELECT [qry_Records].[Tool_ID], [qry_Records].[Cal_Date]," _
    & "[qry_Records].[Cal_By], [qry_Records].[As_Received], " _
    & "[qry_Records].[Result], [qry_Records].[Next_Due], " _
    & "[qry_Records].[Due] FROM [qry_Records]" _
    & " WHERE [qry_Records].[Due] < Day;"

subform_View_Search_Records.Form.RecordSource = SQL
```

I tried to use different variations to quote the Day variable at the end of the SQL String such as below but nothing works:

```
& " WHERE [qry_Records].[Due] < ""Day"";"
& " WHERE [qry_Records].[Due] < '"Day"';"
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a couple of ampersands

```
& " WHERE [qry_Records].[Due] < " & Day & ";"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
SQL = "SELECT [Tool_ID], [Cal_Date]," _
    & "[Cal_By], [As_Received], " _
    & "[Result], [Next_Due], " _
    & "[Due] FROM [qry_Records]" _
    & " WHERE [Due] < " & format$(txtDays, "\#dd\/mm\/yyyy\#")

subform_View_Search_Records.Form.RecordSource = SQL
```

The final ";" is useless.

Comment: This works too! but i think Richard's answer is the one im looking for. Thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: They are more or less equivalent. I have just added some extra formatting make sure it would work independently of the user's regional settings (French or German for instance)